# anaconda change 'base' environment permanently to a different environment 'myenv' to startup at terminal openings

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, library

I would like to cahnge the 'base' install environemnt that inisiates when I start a terminal to an a diferent environment that i have created called 'myenv' anaconda evironment.

I want that 'myenv' stats every thime wen I star the terinal.

I have turned off the 'base' environemnt from initaiating.
`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This belongs better on stackoverflow, where indeed it has been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28436769/10495893

Comment: The accepted answer say it is not possible permanently. The answer after [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777297/10270590) answers it for macOS and Windows and I have a Linux where the answer does not works.